# How to implement this R Poisson distribution in Python?

Tags: python, r, poisson

I've coded something in R but I can't seem to do the same in Python.

Below is the code - it definitely works in R.

I am having trouble with the Python syntax to achieve the same with `numpy`.

```
myMaxAC = qpois(p=as.numeric(0.95),
                lambda=(121412)*(0.005))
```

For clarity, `0.95` is the confidence interval, `121412` is my population size, and `0.005` is a frequency within the population.

I just want to know how to get the same answer in Python, which incidentally is 648.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you also included your Python code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this using `poisson.ppf`:

```
from scipy.stats import poisson
myMaxAC = poisson.ppf(0.95, (121412)*(0.005))
print(myMaxAC)
648.0
```